# Pegar sql Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Bom dia.
Estou com o seguinte problema, necessito pegar o sql executado pelo hibernate e salvar em uma string.
Porem não tenho ideia de como fazer isso, alguém poderia dar uma ajuda?

Comment: Você precisa que seja impressa no console ou precisa salvar mesmo numa variável? O que você precisa fazer com essa informação?

Comment: Necessito salvar em uma String. Pois depois tenho que gravar ela no banco, para um sistema de Log.

Comment: Já que é para logs recomendo usar log4j. Dá uma olhada no artigo: https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-configure-log4j-in-hibernate-project/

Comment: Então eu usei o log4j e o p6spy, porem eles não atende minha necessidade. teria q pegar em tempo de execução o SQL.

Comment: Tá usando Query em todas as consultas do hibernate? Se tiver pode chamar o método getQueryString() para cada query.

Comment: Vai funcionar sim quando e um select, no meu caso tenho que pegar(update, insert e delete), porem estou usando a session para fazer isso (session.save(obj)).

Comment: Nesse caso não usaria o session, mas sim o query.executeUpdate(). Aí vale a mesma resposta que já postei. Agora tem que ver o impacto de utilizar dessa forma.

Comment: Obrigado, Giuliana deu certo :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizando org.hibernate.Query do Hibernate (que é a prática mais comum quando alguém desenvolve consultas usando Hibernate) é possível recuperar a string da query utilizando o método getQueryString():

```
org.hibernate.Query query = session.createQuery("from Entidade where id= :id ");
query.setParameter("id", "1");
String queryString = query.getQueryString();
```

Você só vai precisar persistir a variável queryString no teu banco de logs.

Referência: https://antoniogoncalves.org/2012/05/24/how-to-get-the-jpqlsql-string-from-a-criteriaquery-in-jpa/

Comment: Pode adicionar um exemplo para que o link seja apenas referencia?

Comment: Sim, vou adicionar aqui!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar um `appender` específico para o log de SQLs gerados pelo Hibernate e fazer com que este log salve os SQLs em um arquivo específico. Um arquivo diferente será gerado por dia, graças ao `DailyRollingFileAppender`:

**log4j.properties**

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO, hb
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=warn
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql=debug
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.jdbc=debug

log4j.appender.hb=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.hb.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.hb.Threshold=TRACE

log4j.appender.hb.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.hb.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=log/sql-gerado-pelo-hibernate-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
```

No seu **persistence.xml** ou **hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
<property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>
```

Altere `log/sql-gerado-pelo-hibernate.log` para o diretório e arquivo que desejar. Se quiser salvar na pasta `/tmp` (se estiver no Linux), pode usar `/tmp/sql-gerado-pelo-hibernate.log`.

Precisa testar o código acima (fiz baseado [neste](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2538954/2387977) e [neste](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8888867/2387977)).

Como é gerado um arquivo diferente por dia, você pode depois ler o arquivo do dia anterior, recuperar todo o conteúdo dele e salvar no banco de dados. Nesse meu exemplo você não estará lendo o arquivo ao mesmo tempo que o Log4j estará gravando. Você até pode tentar isto se quiser, mas precisará controlar na leitura do arquivo o que você já leu e não leu ainda, antes de salvar no banco de dados.